# NLShimImpersonate Error 5023 - SQL Server Express - AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, aws, sql-server-express

I'm seeing a ton of these `security_error_ring_buffer_recorded`, `error 5023`, events in my AWS RDS SqlExpress instance. I noticed this while trying to investigate timeout errors I started getting in my .Net app. However, I do not see any failed logins but I have a suspicion it may be related to what I am experiencing, which is occasional timeouts.

I've used the following queries to attempt to identify the root cause but to no avail:

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar(30), GETDATE(), 121) as runtime,
dateadd (ms, (a.[Record Time] - sys.ms_ticks), GETDATE()) as [Notification_Time],
a.* , sys.ms_ticks AS [Current Time]
FROM
(SELECT
x.value('(//Record/Error/ErrorCode)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS [ErrorCode],
x.value('(//Record/Error/CallingAPIName)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS [CallingAPIName],
x.value('(//Record/Error/APIName)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS [APIName],
x.value('(//Record/Error/SPID)[1]', 'int') AS [SPID],
x.value('(//Record/@id)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Record Id],
x.value('(//Record/@type)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS [Type],
x.value('(//Record/@time)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Record Time]
FROM (SELECT CAST (record as xml) FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
WHERE ring_buffer_type = 'RING_BUFFER_SECURITY_ERROR') AS R(x)) a
CROSS JOIN sys.dm_os_sys_info sys
ORDER BY a.[Record Time] ASC


DECLARE @dftrc nvarchar(256)
SELECT  @dftrc=CAST(value as nvarchar(256)) FROM  fn_trace_getinfo(default)  WHERE  property = 2
SELECT  * FROM fn_trace_gettable (@dftrc,default ) WHERE  EventClass= 20 ORDER BY starttime DESC


EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Login failed' 


;WITH RingBufferConnectivity as
(   SELECT
        records.record.value('(/Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS [RecordID],
        records.record.value('(/Record/ConnectivityTraceRecord/RecordType)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS [RecordType],
        records.record.value('(/Record/ConnectivityTraceRecord/RecordTime)[1]', 'datetime') AS [RecordTime],
        records.record.value('(/Record/ConnectivityTraceRecord/SniConsumerError)[1]', 'int') AS [Error],
        records.record.value('(/Record/ConnectivityTraceRecord/State)[1]', 'int') AS [State],
        records.record.value('(/Record/ConnectivityTraceRecord/Spid)[1]', 'int') AS [Spid],
        records.record.value('(/Record/ConnectivityTraceRecord/RemoteHost)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS [RemoteHost],
        records.record.value('(/Record/ConnectivityTraceRecord/RemotePort)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS [RemotePort],
        records.record.value('(/Record/ConnectivityTraceRecord/LocalHost)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS [LocalHost]
    FROM
    (   SELECT CAST(record as xml) AS record_data
        FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
        WHERE ring_buffer_type= 'RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY'
    ) TabA
    CROSS APPLY record_data.nodes('//Record') AS records (record)
)
SELECT RBC.*, m.text
FROM RingBufferConnectivity RBC
LEFT JOIN sys.messages M ON
    RBC.Error = M.message_id AND M.language_id = 1033
WHERE RBC.RecordType='Error' --Comment Out to see all RecordTypes
ORDER BY RBC.RecordTime DESC
```

Here is a detailed look at the 5023 event:

> api_name  ImpersonateSecurityContext
>
> call_stack    0x00007FF97C080B89 
>   0x00007FF97BFAE8AF  0x00007FF97BFB0BB5  0x00007FF97BFAD741 
>   0x00007FF97BFACBE2  0x00007FF97C080BA4  0x00007FF97BFB34C8 
>   0x00007FF97BE502F3  0x00007FF97B0D57BD  0x00007FF97B0D55A5 
>   0x00007FF97B0D51FD  0x00007FF97B0F0D18  0x00007FF97B0F0DB0 
>   0x00007FF97B0F08D7  0x00007FF97B0F1038  0x00007FF99BD213D2
>
> calling_api_name  NLShimImpersonate
>
> error_code    5023
>
> id    5023

I'm also see a `connectivity_ring_buffer_recorded` event, but far less frequent, maybe 1:1000. However, I believe it is related, please correct me if I'm wrong. Here is the important detailed information from that event:

> sni_consumer_error    17830
>
> sni_error 0
>
> state 107
>
> tds_flags DisconnectDueToReadError, NetworkErrorFoundInInputStream,
>   NormalDisconnect
>
> tds_input_buffer_error    10054
>
> type  LoginTimers

Honestly not sure how to begin troubleshooting this issue with the AWS RDS Instance. The only problem is the timeouts, but I have other processes running in parallel with no issue using identical sql login credentials and I don't see any failed logins anywhere which makes me think the error code is erroneous or I'm misapprehending the error codes and their implications.

I've tried googling this and scoured SO, but haven't found a solution, or similar problem, e.g. the queries I tried executing should have returned failed logins.

My AWS forums post link: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=814125&#814125

Comment: Have you contacted AWS support?

Comment: @BrentOzar I cannot submit a technical support request because I'm only on the basic plan. I'm currently waiting for my "lockout" timer on AWS forums to expire. Apparently, you have to wait a few hours after activating your forum account to make a post. However, I plan on posting in the AWS support forums as soon as possible.

Comment: On a side note, thanks for all your work. I frequent the blog posts and use the Blitz scripts regularly.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! Yeah, I would definitely post over there and hope an AWS employee replies. You're on a double-obscure-whammy here (RDS on Express) that just doesn't see a lot of market adoption.